# Change a symbol of a component on LTspice

Tags: ltspice, symbol

I have downloaded the PA107 microtechnology component library. The symbol is displayed like this:

[image]

However I want to change that symbol to be the symbol of an amplifier. How can I do that on LTspice?

[image]

Comment: Hint: make a new schematic containing the existing PA107. Connect a pin to each of the PA107's pins, you can give those pins any name you like. That schematic will only contain the PA107, wires and pins, nothing more. Then from that schematic, create a **new symbol**. That symbol can be made to look like anything you want.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/videos/5579253506001.html This may help! I am sure you figured it out by now but for anyone else searching.

Comment: @Tam  Thanks - I'll make this a comment to the answer. Welcome to Stack Exchange EE.